# Can not create db table in django migration

Tags: django, database-migration, django-migrations

I have 2 apps "app1", "app2" in my django project.

When I ran `python3 manage.pymakemigrations`, I can see

```
...
Migrations for 'app1':
...
Migrations for 'app2':
...
```

But when I ran `python3 manage.py migrate`, I got error saying

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

"auth_user" is db table for app1.User model, also is what AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to.

I tried to run migrate separately. It is fine for app2. But when I run `python3 manage.py migrate` app1, I got

```
No migrations to apply.
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I cannot find a solution for my case, anyone can help?

The user model code:

> class User(AbstractBaseUser, Base):
>
> ```
> USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
>     (1, 'supervisor'), 
>     (2, 'admin'),
>     (4, 'support'),
> )
>
> email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
> name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
> password = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
> last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
> active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
> user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
>     choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
>     default=2
> )
>
> USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
> objects = UserManager()
>
> class Meta:
>     db_table = 'auth_user'
>     app_label = 'admin_portal'
>
> def __str__(self):
>     return str(self.email)
>
> @property
> def is_admin(self):
>     return self.user_type == 1
>
> @property
> def is_active(self):
>     return self.active
> ```

Comment: You first should run the migration for the `auth` app, since that will define the table for the `User` model, so `python3 manage.py migrate auth`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations` then ran `python3 manage.py migrate auth`, Still got `No migrations to apply.
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command separately for each app:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations app1
python3 manage.py makemigrations app2
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help

Comment: So, share the model codes of both apps.
Also, delete the created Migrate folder files once and restart makemigrations.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea but try this. Delete all migration, cache files nd do run makemigrations to each app not entirely.then run the migrate

Comment: I have tried to delete all migrations files and migrating from the start, still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but because I tried modifying the the AUTH_USER during development.

In my case what worked was downgrading django to 2.0, deleted all migrations and had to drop the database.

But it worked.

Then when upgrading to 4.0 had to apply "auth" migration but worked fine.